# How to create a curve that will best fit the points in my plot

Tags: matlab

```
lmd = 10;
k = poissrnd(lmd,1,100000);
q = exp(-lmd).*((lmd.^k)./factorial(k));
plot(k,q,'.')
```

I cant connect my points through plot() since it comes out a jumbled mess. How can I plot a curve of the points I have that will best fit the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use curve fitting toolbox of the MATLAB and it provides you with so many fitting options. You can find which option works best for you by try and error.

If you want to use spline, use `yy=spline(x,y,xx)` command. Then use `plot(xx,yy)` to plot the curve.

Answer (score -1):

Sort the data

```
[x,i] = sort(k);
y = q(i);
plot(x,y);
```

If you have to "fit" the data, try cubic spline interpolation.

Comment: Is there a better method that provides a smoother curve?

Comment: Sorting destroys your data. Say it's a time series, you suddenly jumble your time series to get a nice line. That's never a good idea. Cubic spline interpolation might, provided the data is not too noisy and is a *cubic fit*. No-one knows a cubic fit will be the best for your data.

Comment: How do I use the spline function for this data?